# ¿Cómo puedo copiar una tabla?

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Quisiera saber si existe la posibilidad de copiar una tabla con un botón, que al momento de dar clic en el botón me copie la tabla al portapapeles para posteriormente ir y pegarla con <kbd><kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd></kbd> en un correo de *GMail*, pero igual en formato de tabla, he visto distintos ejemplos pero no funcionan. Anexo el código de cómo construyo mi tabla, estoy usando *Visual Studio 2015 (MVC)*.

```
<div class="container" style="max-height:250px; min-height:10px; overflow:auto;">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tbRecetas">
        <thead style="background-color: #1359A1; color: #ffffff">
            <tr>
                <th class="hidden">
                    RecetaId
                </th>
                <th>
                    Asignar
                </th>
                <th>
                    Tipo surtido
                </th>
                <th>
                    Estatus
                </th>
                <th>
                    Folio Receta
                </th>
                <th>
                    Código EAN
                </th>
                <th>
                    Descripción de Medicamento
                </th>
                <th>
                    Unidades
                </th>                   
                <th class="hidden">
                    Elegibilidad
                </th>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody id="tbodyRecetas">
            @if (ViewBag.Asignar.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in ViewBag.Asignar)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="hidden">@item.RecetaId</td>
                        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="checkTable" checked /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="tipo_@item.RecetaId" id="tipoDomicilio" checked>Domicilio
                            <input type="radio" name="tipo2_@item.RecetaId" id="tipoSucursal">Sucursal
                        </td>
                        <td>@item.Estatus</td>
                        <td>@item.FolioReceta</td>
                        <td>@item.CodigoEAN</td>
                        <td>@item.DescripcionMedicamento</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@item.Unidades</td>                            
                        <td class="hidden">@item.Elegibilidad</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <template>
                    <p class="alert alert-info">No se encontraron registros</p>
                </template>}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

> Quisiera saber si existe la posibilidad de copiar una tabla con un botón, que al momento de dar clic en el botón me copie la tabla al portapapeles

De existir posibilidad, existe.

En tu pregunta mencionas:

> he visto distintos ejemplos pero no funcionan

Esos ejemplos deberían estar incluidos en tu pregunta y eso permitiría revisar lo que has intentado.

Ejecuta el siguiente ejemplo, dale click en el botón y luego un <kbd><kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd></kbd>, intenté en *MS Word* y copió bien los formatos.

```js
function selectElementContents(el) {
 var body = document.body, range, sel;
 if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
  range = document.createRange();
  sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  try {
   range.selectNodeContents(el);
   sel.addRange(range);
  } catch (e) {
   range.selectNode(el);
   sel.addRange(range);
  }
 } else if (body.createTextRange) {
  range = body.createTextRange();
  range.moveToElementText(el);
  range.select();
 }
 document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
 <thead>
  <tr><th>Heading</th><th>Heading</th></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="select table"
 onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById('table') );">
```

Referencia de *SOen*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54674716/3613462